# How to structure my query to get a consistent result using sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to find Countries where all cities have more inhabitants than Nepal's most populous city.
I don't know how to structure my query.

To find Nepal's most populous city :

```
SELECT t.Name,MAX(t.Population) 
FROM City AS t 
INNER JOIN Country AS c ON t.CountryCode=c.Code 
WHERE C.Name='Nepal';
```

> Kathmandu|591835

To find the sum of populations by country :

```
SELECT c.Name, SUM(t.Population) 
FROM City AS t 
INNER JOIN Country AS c ON c.Code=t.CountryCode 
GROUP BY c.Code Limit 5;
```

> Aruba|29034
> Afghanistan|2332100
> Angola|2561600
> Anguilla|1556
> Albania|270000

I have 3 tables available :

> "Country" ("Code"  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"Name"  NOT NULL ,"Continent"  NOT NULL  DEFAULT ('Asia') ,"Region"  NOT NULL ,"SurfaceArea"  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0.00) ,"IndepYear"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"Population"  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,"LifeExpectancy"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"GNP"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"GNPOld"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"LocalName"  NOT NULL ,"GovernmentForm"  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (null) ,"HeadOfState"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"Capital"  DEFAULT (NULL) ,"Code2"  NOT NULL );
>
> "City" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "Name" CHAR NOT NULL , "CountryCode" CHAR NOT NULL , "District" CHAR NOT NULL , "Population" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0);
>
> "CountryLanguage" ("CountryCode" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "Language" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "IsOfficial" VARCHAR NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'F', "Percentage" FLOAT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0.0, PRIMARY KEY ("CountryCode", "Language"));

I've tried this :

```
SELECT c.Name,t.Population 
FROM City t 
INNER JOIN Country c ON c.Code=t.CountryCode 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t.Population) FROM City t INNER JOIN Country c ON c.Code=t.CountryCode) > (SELECT MAX(t.Population) FROM City t INNER JOIN Country c ON t.CountryCode=c.Code WHERE C.Name='Nepal') GROUP BY c.Name LIMIT 5;
```

> Afghanistan|1780000
> Albania|270000
> Algeria|2168000
> American Samoa|5200
> Andorra|21189

Which is wrong because we get a result including for example (American Samoa | 5200)

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
select max(c.population) maxpop
from city c inner join country t
on t.code = c.countrycode
where t.name = 'Nepal'
```

you get the population of the most populous city of 'Nepal'.
Now use it as a subquery with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from country t
where not exists (
  select 1 from city
  where countrycode = t.code
  and population <= (
    select max(c.population)
    from city c inner join country t
    on t.code = c.countrycode
    where t.name = 'Nepal'
  )
)
```

For better performance use a CTE instead of subquery:

```
with cte as (
    select max(c.population) maxpop
    from city c inner join country t
    on t.code = c.countrycode
    where t.name = 'Nepal'
)  
select t.* from country t
where not exists (
  select 1 from city
  where countrycode = t.code
  and population <= (select maxpop from cte)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` with `min()`

```
select co.name
from country co join
     city ci
     on co.code = ci.countrycode
group by co.name
having min(ci.city) > (select max(ci2.population)
                       from country co2 join
                            city ci2
                            on co2.code = ci2.countrycode
                       where co2.name = 'Nepal'
                      );
```

This is even simpler with window functions:

```
select name
from (select co.name,
             ci.population,
             max(case when co.name = 'Nepal' then population end) over () as nepal_max_population
      from country co join
           city ci
           on co.code = ci.countrycode
     ) c
group by name, nepal_max_population
having min(population) > nepal_max_population;
```